# ios UI is not scalable for my storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, uistoryboard

I'm new to ios.

I have created a storyboard. I gave it's view size and location.

I intended it be scalable, so I used ration size and relative spacing.

However when I run the ios simulator I see the storyboard very different on iphone 6S and iphone 5 for example.

Here is my mock:
[image]

Here is my [source-code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o0Sz9GfVijHMhnc88ZuVs6LH0rS9AB5nGpXUIayyvh8/edit?usp=sharing)

iphone 4s  simulator:
[image]

iphone 5s simulator:
[image]

what can i do to make it scale right?

Comment: You should read about Autolayout: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/) is a better place than Google Docs to post raw XML. [Example.](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/d8f44f8717fd6dccf777).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Auto Layout. While in your storyboard, click your ViewController and then go to the attributes inspector (in the pane on the right side of Xcode, the "attributes inspector" is the tab that looks like a down arrow), and for "size" make sure "inferred" is selected. If it is not selected, then click the drop down menu and select it. Then when you are placing objects on the view controller scene, you must add the appropriate constraints at times to ensure that everything gets scaled properly on different screen sizes. Read here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html